# print permutations of all strings in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print the permutations of all the members in a list,but my script is printing the permutations of only last member of list i.e 'DMNCT'.

```
from itertools import permutations
element_all=['EESE', 'TTDT', 'SAIFE', 'DMNCT']
i=0
for i in range (len(element_all)):
    perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(element_all[i])]
print perms
```

It seems that my for loop is not working correctly.I am fairly new to python.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Each iteration of the `for` loop, you're overwriting the previous value of `perms`. You'll need to save them somewhere (append to a list, maybe?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're replacing `perms` each loop.  You should define the list outside the loop and then `extend` it inside the loop.

```
from itertools import permutations
element_all=['EESE', 'TTDT', 'SAIFE', 'DMNCT']
perms = []
for i in element_all:
    perms.extend([''.join(p) for p in permutations(i)])
print perms
```

Or define the list all at once in a comprehension

```
perms = [''.join(p) for i in element_all for p in permutations(i)]
```